# Graceful way of closing a broken SSH pipe on OSX?

Tags: macos

I've heard that the shift + tilda + period is supposed to close a hanging ssh pipe, but I can not simply ever get it to work. So my question to stackoverflow is, how do I gracefully close a broken SSH pipe on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

When I type `<enter> ~ .` I leave the ssh session. This is on a German keyboard where I have to type `<alt>+n <space>` (where `<alt>+n` means to press `n` while holding down the `alt` key) to get a tilde. So the key sequence is for me: `<enter> <alt>+n <space> .`.